# Замешанный или замешенный - как отличить? Могут ли подходить оба слова?

Tags: орфография

> И снова мы виделись через чужие головы и разные судьбы, замешанные в
>   одном большом котле.

Я бы нарисовала *замешенные*, но не уверена.

Месить судьбы в котле?

Вовлечь их же в котёл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что здесь подойдёт причастие только от глагола "замесить" (люди могут быть в чём-то замешаны, *вмешиваясь* в делишки, но их судьбы только "месят" в котлах):

> Колобок был *замеш**а**н* в побеге, будучи при этом *замеш**е**нным* на сметане.

Answer (score 1):

Можно представить себе *перемешанные судьбы* (от глагола ***мешать***), глагол ***месить*** смотрится немного странно:

ЗАМЕСИТЬ, что. Приготовить **однородную вязкую массу**, размешивая, растирая что-л. в воде (в жидкости). З. тесто.

**Конечно, значение переносное**, но в этом случае можно использовать нар.-разг. вариант ***замешать***, получится такое компромиссное решение.

ЗАМЕШАТЬ,  замешанный; -шан, Нар.-разг. =Замесить